# Calibrated p-value

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

Why do people very rarely report the calibrated p-value which is: $$\mathcal{P}(p) = \frac{-ep \log(p)}{1-ep \log(p)}$$

This gives the probability that one falsely rejects the null hypothesis (i.e. Type 1 error). It is a lower bound.

Comment: Do you mind providing a reference for the calibrated p-value for those unfamiliar?

Comment: What is $e$ in your formula?

Comment: @Stephen Kolassa: It is the transcendental number e.

Comment: [here](http://www.debunkers.org/Library/files/block_0/P-values.pdf) is one reference. Google revealed a few

Answer (score 3):

The calibrated p-value does not contain any more information than the p-value does (one can transform them back and forth). Just because the p-value is historically wider known, it is still the most reported. If one would like the calibrated p-value, they can simply calculate it by the function you have stated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hotly debated topic.

In my view, the benefit of reporting a calibrated value, even though by itself it does not provide additional information, would be ease of interpretation as the p-value is often misinterpreted
[P-values – a chronic conundrum by Jian Gao in BMC Medical Research Methodology volume 20, Article number: 167 (2020)](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-020-01051-6), "the calibrated p-values (the probability that a treatment does not work) should be reported in research papers".

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are trying to build a permanent 
repository of high-quality statistical information in the 
form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of 
link-only answers, due to linkrot. Can you post a full 
citation & a summary of the 
information at the link, in case it goes dead?